# как правильно работать со строками в СИ?

Tags: c, строки

Стокнулся с таким интересным фактом. Что в СИ++ есть класс `string`, а в QT фраемворке есть класс для работы с строками `QString`. А в СИ класса для работы с строками нету ((((

И появляться две проблемы. Первая, это работа с размером char массива. Не когда не знаешь насколько будет длинна строка.

Вторая, просто "эмоциональная" что бы вывести строку можно воспользоваться `fprint` который можно дополнить `%d`, в СИ++ `string` можно приплюсовать в `string` и всё, вот тебе новая "полная" строка, в Qt надо добавить (вызвать в строке) функцию .arg, это всё **интуитивно понятные методы**. А в СИ так жестоко и не интуитивно в отношении пользователя.

По чему в СИ такого класса для работы с строками нету ??

Как это обойти ??

Как правильно работать с строками  ??

Comment: `...А в СИ так жестоко и не интуитивно в отношении пользователя...` -- почему вы решили, что Си это язык для *пользователей*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C нет класса `string` потому, что C не является объектно-ориентированным языком, и в нём в принципе нет классов.

Язык C++ разработал Бьярн Страустрап в 1983-м году, долгое время он назывался «C с классами» Оригинальный C появился гораздо раньше, в 1969-м.

Чтобы работать со строками в C, применяют функции стандартной библиотеки, описанные в заголовочном файле **string.h**, такие как `strcpy` (копирование строки), `strcmp` (сравнение строк), `strlen` (определение длины строки).

К сожалению, эти функции слишком низкого уровня для задач обработки текста, поэтому в программах на чистом C нередко встречается переполнение буфера, что иногда используют для взломов.

Поэтому в стандартную библиотеку были включены функции, умеющие корректно работать с буферами, например `snprintf` вместо `sprintf`.

Тем не менее, их использование всё ещё трудоёмко и требует аккуратности. Вместо статического буфера `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]` вам придётся использовать динамический, вручную выделяя и освобождая память.

Answer (score 2):

В C нет классов, так как C рассматривается как язык ассемблера среди языков высокого уровня, и от него уже давно произошли другие объектно-ориентированные C-подобные языки, которые добавляют средства для работы с классами.

То есть каждый язык занимает свою нишу.

Что касается вывода конкатенации строки с числом, то это несложно выполнить с помощью спецификаторов формата. Например,

```
printf( "%s$d", "2 * 2 = ", 2 * 2 );
```

Для работы со строками придется самому перевыделять динамически память, используя функцию `realloc`, объявленную в заголовке `<stdlib.h>`, когда требуется изменить размер строки.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже отметили, в Си нет классов.
Почитай про динамическое выделение памяти (malloc, realloc, calloc) и изучи string.h и stdio.h
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/String.h

Вообще Си очень лаконичный язык - понять его и изучить все синтаксические возможности достаточно просто. Советую иметь под рукой книгу: Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи "Язык программирования Си". Будет полезно, раз вы работаете с С/С++ и Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в древности неправильного обращения со строками в Си. Во всех начальных уроках показывают так:

```
char * str = "Hello world" ;
int str_len = strlen(str);
```

Это **очень** неправильно. Здесь в переменную записывается указатель на первую букву , а программа не знает какой длины строка и вызывается функция `strlen`. И даже массив служебный, основываясь на длине этой строки невозможно создать, так-как это число **не** константа.

Правильно записывать так :

```
char const str[]="Hello again";
int const str_len = sizeof(str)-1;
bool arr[sizeof(str)-1];
```

Здесь совершенно всё по-другому. `str` - это **массив** фиксированной длины включая завершающий символ `'\0'`. Количество значащих букв по-этому меньше на одну. Размер строки и массива определена в момент компиляции и по-этому можно создать нужный вспомогательный массив. А так-же если-что передать размер строки в другие функции **без** использования `strlen`. Чтобы передать строку в функцию придётся обойтись указателем (сам массив целиком нельзя) и размер (известный во время компиляции).

```
// gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c11 -Os cor_str.c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

typedef
struct{
  char const * str;
  size_t len ;
} Str ;

void f(Str s){
  printf("f:s.str=%s\n",s.str);
  printf("f:s.len=%ld\n",s.len);
}

int main() {
  char const * old_s = "123";
  // размер строки без конечного символа '\0'
  // вычисляется в момент выполнения программы
  printf("strlen(old_s)=%ld\n",strlen(old_s));
  // storage size of ‘old_arr’ isn’t constant
  // static  char  old_arr[strlen(old_s)];
  // размер указателя
  printf("sizeof(old_s)=%ld\n",sizeof(old_s));
  // размер массива с конечным char '\0'
  // вычисляется в момент компиляции
  // строка засунута в код
  // char  const cor_s[]="abc";
  // строка есть программе
  static  char  const cor_s[]="abc";
  printf("sizeof(cor_s)=%ld\n",sizeof(cor_s));
  printf("cor_s=%s\n",cor_s);
  static  char  cor_arr[sizeof(cor_s)];
  Str s = {cor_s,sizeof(cor_s)-1};
  f(s);
}
```

Comment: Да, я также это заметил , **многие держаться за 1978 год** , хотя последняя реализация си  2011 года :3  сам сейчас читаю  книгу "Язык Си в 21 веке", очень полезно

Comment: @timob256, обратите внимание, что в современном Си *можно писать*  `char newstr[n];`, где `n` это не константа, а переменная, значение которой перед объявлением `newstr` задаст размер этой строки в стеке, а также на функцию [asprintf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), которая создает строки с форматированным содержимым в динамической памяти.

Comment: @avp Ваше предложение это совсем не современный Си, у меня он выдаёт ошибку : `storage size of ‘old_arr’ isn’t constant`. Посмотрите мой пример и все опции.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, очевидно же, что это не относится к **static** (память этого класса распределяется исключительно во время трансляции). Уберите `static`, напишите `char  old_arr[strlen(old_s) + 1];` /  +1 это чтобы завершающий nil, который sizeof учитывает, тоже поместился